# Generic class type - static and abstract methods in JAVA

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, static-methods

I have a generic class which looks like:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends AbstractClass>
```

AbstractClass is, of course, an abstract class.
FirstAbstractClass and SecondAbstractClass both extends AbstractClass

the constructor of GenericClass is:

```
public GenericClass(Class<T> cls) {}
```

GenericClass also has a member, `String field`.

I want that each class extends AbstractClass will have a method which return String, and the field will get this value. In GenericClass' constructor:

```
this.field = T.getField();
```

The problem is - i don't want to create an instance of T just for that, and i can't make a static method in the abstract class and override it in FirstAbstractClass and SecondAbstractClass.

Comment: @yshavit Rolled back :)

Comment: You don't really have any alternatives other than the ones you describe.  But this is probably a bad idea in the first place; the standard way to do this is just to have one abstract method for all subclasses of AbstractClass, instead of having them have different names in each.

Comment: I know, but for this to work i have to create an instance of T, just for that...

Comment: The options as I see it: 1) change the design to pass around subclass instances, so you can call an appropriate abstract method, 2) if it's a small number of statically known subclasses, push up all of the necessary information into `GenericClass`, such as by storing a `Map<Class<? extends AbstractClass>, String>` populated in a static initialization block, 3) use reflection to introspect on the subclasses for a static method that matches what you need.

Comment: I saw this problem so many times... it does not have nice solutions

Comment: This is an XY problem. There is no reason why the method has to be a `static` method of `T` at all. Any function with a compatible signature would do, thus, you could just let the constructor accept a `Supplier<String>`, and maybe drop the `Class<T>` parameter. If you do that, you could still implement the `Supplier<String>` inside the `FirstAbstractClass` and `SecondAbstractClass` using a method reference to a `static` method inside said classes, but whether you do or not does not carry any semantic value.